# How to encrypt glide cache data?

Tags: android, security, caching, encryption, android-glide

**How to encrypt glide cache data ?**

In general by downloading the cache of glide from emulators (*android studio device explorer*). We can be see them as clear images .

**How to prevent this ?**

**Outcome I need is** :- No one should be able to see the cache files. it should be in encrypted format.

Comment: By default, Glide caches images on what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). This is inaccessible by ordinary users. You are able to see them in Device File Explorer only because you are testing a `debug` build of your app. If you test a `release` build of your app, you will not be able to see the images.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
But is it possible to make it difficult to see by encryption? 
Even in rooted devices, and by any reverse engineering. It should not be visible.

Comment: "Even in rooted devices, and by any reverse engineering. It should not be visible." -- then you need to stop downloading images, as those downloads can be intercepted.

Comment: You are still welcome to implement [your own Glide disk cache](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#disk-cache), or eliminate the disk cache, but that's at best an incomplete solution to the problem of an attacker getting access to those images.